# Java EE6> Packaging JSF facelets (xhtml) and ManagedBeans as JAR

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jar, facelets, packaging

Is it possible to package JSF facelets and ManagedBeans into a JAR file? So that we can use this code and UI combination in different war/ear projects?

I am not talking about JSF Components!

If yes - can you point me to a tutorial or blog post

I need details about the Jar structure and additional files needed in the Jar?

Thanks Max

Answer (score 17):

Yes, that's definitely possible, assuming that you're using JSF 2.0, part of Java EE 6.

As to the managed beans and other JSF classes like validators, converters, etc, just annotate them with `@ManagedBean`, `@FacesValidator`, `@FacesConverter`, etc and package them in the JAR the usual way. You only need to provide a JSF 2.0 compatible `/META-INF/faces-config.xml` file in the JAR.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
</faces-config>
```

This way JSF will be triggered to scan the classes in the JAR for JSF specific annotations. Alternatively you can also just register them in the JAR's `faces-config.xml` the JSF 1.x way.

As to Facelets resources, just drop them in `/META-INF/resources` folder of the JAR. It'll be treated the same way as public webcontent of the WAR.

#### See also:

- [Packaging Facelets files (templates, includes, composites) in a JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531432/jsf2-pages-into-a-jar)

Comment: is it possible to add the the jar file in the ear lib directory? or it should be placed under the war WEB-INF/lib directory?

Comment: Create answer which work quite well for my managed beans. But how can I deal with composites? I have some composite:implementations laying around in a package which is a view to a some EJBs. I want to use these in my main application and I do not want to collect all composites in the main WAR. Inside the containing WAR I can call them by a tag like <e:composite/> where 'e:' is the name space to the library. The resource resolver does not seem to resolve this.

Comment: @BalusC What if META-INF/faces-config.xml does not contain beans info? I mean if the managed bean use annotations? Will it go? Or the faces-config.xml here just needed to make recognize IDE that this is the jsf lib only?