# How to access the JSP file from WEB-INF/lib/module.jar

Tags: jsp, jsf

I want to create my web application modularized. By this User could able to install/unstalled the specific module. When user installed the module, one jar (which contains JSP files, java classes and all resources) will copied to the webapplication .war file inside WEB-INF/lib folder.

So can i access the JSP file from WEB-INF/lib/module.jar?
Currently at presentation layer i have used JSF. So in JSF do we have some way to access JSP file from .jar files?

Comment: If you were using JSP's successor Facelets, it would have been easy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104498/jee6-packaging-jsf-facelets-xhtml-and-managedbeans-as-jar Did you consider using Facelets instead of JSP? It works for JSF 1.2 as well. See also http://facelets.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur quick help.

Comment: For now i have put FaceletsResourceResolver.java in Module1's SRC->com.example folder.
and also put one image in /META-INF/resources/images folder of Module1's META-INF folder. And try to access this image in Module1's JSP like.. 

<tr:image source="#{resource['test.jpg']}" inlineStyle="height:100px; width:100px"></tr:image>  
or 
<tr:image source="test.jpg" inlineStyle="height:100px; width:100px"></tr:image>  

But unfortunatly i doesnt see that image on the JSP. and JSP is currently in the WebContent folder.
Even i have put JSP in /META-INF/resources/ folder. that also doesn't work.

Comment: I didn't mean that... It was not an answer to the question. It was just a comment. If you consider upgrading from JSP to Facelets, then this will be easily possible. But this means that you have to convert all JSP files to Facelets files.

Comment: After doing some changes in FaceletsResourceResolver Java class i am able to call images from /META-INF/resources of other module. But still I am not able to call JSP files which i have put in /META-INF/resources. For now it is not posible for me to change all JSP files to facelets. Because I have some deadline to finish the work. But in the future we will definitely move to facelets. So do you have any work around to put JSP in the JAR? So that we can access it from browser address bar or include in onother JSP.