# Component Tree not expanding when using ui:debug facelet tag

Tags: debugging, jsf, facelets

I have recently moved the masterLayout template for a web application into an external jar as mentioned in the answer here
[Java EE6> Packaging JSF facelets (xhtml) and ManagedBeans as JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104498/jee6-packaging-jsf-facelets-xhtml-and-managedbeans-as-jar)

Since I am not using any managed beans. I haven't included faces-config.xml in the jar.

I have a local template that extends this masterLayout. The application is running fine. But I noticed that when I open the Debug Output window. The Component Tree does not expand but Scoped Variables does expand nicely. (Before this transition it worked well)

> Local Template
>
> > ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
> >         xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
> >         xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
> >         xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
> >         xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
> >         template="/templates/masterLayout.xhtml"
>
> index.xhtml
>
> > ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
> >         xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
> >         xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
> >         xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
> >         xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui" 
> >         template="/templates/localTemplate.xhtml"

Initially I thought it could be this bug
http://java.net/jira/browse/FACELETS-292
But that was fixed way back in 2008

I am using JSF 2.0.6.FCS, Primefaces 2.2.1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that ..the external project where I was having this masterLayout already was being used for JSF 1.2 project. I just added a JSF 2.0 resource resolver along side with it. So the build script was pulling facelets-1.1.14.jar from that project so JSF2.0 facelets was never being used. So I excluded that jar file from my ivy dependency which solved the problem.