# Managed Bean Classes Separation

Tags: servlets, jsf-2, java-ee-6, managed-bean

I have two projects, I need to reuse same jsf managed bean classes for other projects. 
Is there any way I can create a separate project for jsf managed bean classes + util classes and refer them in all projects I will do.

Comment: just use a utility project and add it to your EAR...

Comment: no it didnt work, jsf facelets dont find managed bean classes at runtime

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the IDE used, create a simple "Java Project" or a "Web Fragment Project" and make sure that it has a JSF 2.0 compatible `/META-INF/faces-config.xml` file in the source folder. Then configure your web projects to include that project as a JAR in the `/WEB-INF/lib` (again, depends on IDE used, in Eclipse just add the module project to *Deployment Assembly* list in web project's properties). Once JSF finds a JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib` with a JSF 2.0 compatible `/META-INF/faces-config.xml`, then JSF will automatically scan the entire JAR for JSF artifacts.

#### See also:

- [Structure for multiple JSF projects with shared code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320486/structure-for-multiple-jsf-projects-with-shared-code)
- [JSF facelets template packaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290482/jsf-facelets-template-packaging/9473487#9473487)

Comment: I am using netbeans 7 and it did find the managed beans on editors but when I compile and deploy at runtime it giving me an error!!!!

Comment: Apparently there's no JSF 2.0 compatible `/META-INF/faces-config.xml` in the JAR, or the project didn't end up as a valid JAR in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`. Sorry, can't help you with more detail with Netbeans as I've never really used it for more than 5 minutes.

Comment: which one are you using eclipse ?

Comment: It should be possible in Netbeans as well. You just need to verify if the project has really ended up as a JAR in the `/WEB-INF/lib` of the built WAR and that there's a JSF 2.0 compatible `/META-INF/faces-config.xml` file in the JAR. In Eclipse, only adding the other project to the build path of the main web project isn't right. That's also a common mistake among Eclipse users. The project has to be added as deployment assembly (which ultimately makes it to end up as JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib`). Perhaps you made exactly this mistake in Netbeans.

Comment: I am gonna give it a try now and let you know the resutls, anyway seems you want to keep your dev ID secret :)

Comment: Oh, of course I am using Eclipse. I've also some hands on experience with IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Java EE 6, if you are willing to use CDI it would be quite of an easy thing to do. I did it myself a couple of times.

Put your Managed Beans in a separated JAR project and import it on the projects you want to use them. The only thing you have to do is use `@Named` instead of `@ManagedBean` and have a beans.xml in /META-INF of both projects. That way you can reference your CDI enabled beans in your facelets pages and also gain the whole flexibility and power of CDI models.