# JSF - Bean declaration inside class of a imported jar not working

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, dependency-properties, code-injection

I have two web jsf projects which potentially could share some classes and beans, to reduce code duplicates.

One is a potential JNDI-ServiceLocator application scoped Bean. (Both web projects access RemoteBeans from same Host)

**JNDI - ServiceLocator Bean:**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "jndiServiceLocatorBean")
@ApplicationScoped
public class JndiServiceLocatorBean implements Serializable
{
    // code to cache jndi references
}
```

**Abstract class with Bean as ManagedProperty:**

```
public abstract class AJndiServiceLocator
{
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{jndiServiceLocatorBean}")
    protected JndiServiceLocatorBean jndiServiceLocatorBean = null;

    public void setJndiServiceLocatorBean(final JndiServiceLocatorBean jndiServiceLocatorBean)
    {
        this.jndiServiceLocatorBean = jndiServiceLocatorBean;
    }
}
```

**Example Bean from one of the projects:**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "testBean")
@ApplicationScoped
public class TestBean extends AJndiServiceLocator implements Serializable
{
    // bean code - can now retrieve remote bean interfaces 
    // from super class
}
```

This code works as expected if the first classes `JndiServiceLocatorBean` and `AJndiServiceLocator` are in the source folder of the project.

But it does not works if I outsource those two classes into a subproject that is shared between both web projects. (Included on build path and marked as deployment entry.)

**Injection Exception that occurs:**

```
Schwerwiegend: Error Rendering View[/index.xhtml]
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Bei der Ressourcen-Einspeisung auf dem verwalteten Bean appBean ist ein Fehler aufgetreten.
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:229)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:105)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSF won't scan every single JAR in the entire classpath for JSF artifacts, that would have been a very expensive job in a large webapp with tens of JARs. JSF will only scan JARs in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder containing a JSF 2.0 compatible `/META-INF/faces-config.xml` file.

Ensure that your JAR conforms this.

- It must be in `/WEB-INF/lib`.
- It must have a `/META-INF/faces-config.xml` with a JSF 2.0 compatible root declaration.

#### See also:

- [Structure for multiple JSF projects with shared code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320486/structure-for-multiple-jsf-projects-with-shared-code/8320738#8320738)
- [JSF facelets template packaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290482/jsf-facelets-template-packaging/9473487#9473487)