# Facelets template not found in a common jar in an exploded deployment

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, servlets, jsf-2, facelets

Here is my **Facelet template** location : **WAR/WEB-INF/lib/common.jar/META-INF/resources/m0/template.xhtml**.

It throws the following **exception** when the war, and the jar in it, are deployed as exploded folders : **Invalid path : /m0/template.xhtml**

It **works** when the war and the jar is deployed as real archives, or when they are exploded in an EAR, but not in a simple WAR.

Additional information :

- The problem is the same on Windows and Linux.
- The problem occurs only in an exploded WAR where common.jar is an exploded folder under WEB-INF/lib.
- The problem does not occur in an exploded EAR where common.jar is a folder under EAR/lib.

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290482/jsf-facelets-template-packaging) that facelets templates are resolved by ExternalContext#getResource() which delegates to ServletContext#getResource() to load resources from /WEB-INF/lib/*.jar!/META-INF/resources. Does it works only with real jars ? Or should I try another implementation of the servlet API ? I'm using Glassfish 3.1.2 with Mojarra 2.1.6.

I want to use an exploded deployment during development since it is much faster to test changes.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Here is the stack trace : `javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException: /help/overview/overview.xhtml @8,32 <ui:composition template="/m0/template.xhtml"> Invalid path : /m0/template.xhtml
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:160)
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:86)
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:152)
 ...`

Comment: As I told, the workaround is to include the WAR in an EAR.