# Deploying backing bean with composite component in separate jar

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, web-deployment, composite-component, backing-beans

I have some difficulties deploying my web app on JBoss AS 6.1. My current Project is separated into the main web app (controller/managed beans & web frontend using JSF 2 facelets) and one jar with the composite components + backing beans. But when I try to access the page I got an error that the specified component type could not be instantiated.

Copying the backing bean into the main web app solves the problem, but this isn't what I want. So is there anything to pay attention to?

The backing bean looks like

```
@FacesComponent(value = "elementBase")
public class ElementBase extends UINamingContainer {
    ...
}
```

and the composite components interface

```
<composite:interface componentType="elementBase">
... some attributes
</composite:interface>
```

The structure of the jar is the following

```
-- META-INF
    |-- resources
    |    |-- components
    |         |-- elementBase.xhtml
-- com
    |-- example
    |    |-- ElementBase.class
```

I've also tried to add `faces-config.xml` within `META-INF` folder, with the component type, but the component type was still not found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through the BalusC's answer to the question [JEE6> Packaging JSF facelets (xhtml) and ManagedBeans as JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104498)

> As to the managed beans and other JSF classes like validators, converters, etc, just annotate them with `@ManagedBean`, `@FacesValidator`, `@FacesConverter`, etc and package them in the JAR the usual way. You only need to provide a JSF 2.0 compatible `/META-INF/faces-config.xml` file in the JAR.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
</faces-config>
```

> This way JSF will be triggered to scan the classes in the JAR for JSF specific annotations. Alternatively you can also just register them in the JAR's faces-config.xml the JSF 1.x way.

and [Java EE6 Tutorial: Application Configuration Resource File](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnawp.html)

> You can have more than one application configuration resource file for an application. The JavaServer Faces implementation finds the configuration file or files by looking for the following:
>
> - A resource named `/META-INF/faces-config.xml` in any of the JAR files in the web application’s `/WEB-INF/lib/` directory and in parent class loaders. If a resource with this name exists, it is loaded as a configuration resource. This method is practical for a packaged library containing some components and renderers. In addition, any file with a name that ends in faces-config.xml is also considered a configuration resource and is loaded as such.
> - A context initialization parameter, `javax.faces.application.CONFIG_FILES`, in your web deployment descriptor file that specifies one or more (comma-delimited) paths to multiple configuration files for your web application. This method is most often used for enterprise-scale applications that delegate to separate groups the responsibility for maintaining the file for each portion of a big application.
> - A resource named faces-config.xml in the `/WEB-INF/` directory of your application. Simple web applications make their configuration files available in this way.

.. I could fix my problem.

## Step by step solution

1. Create backing bean

   ```
   @FacesComponent(value = "elementBase")
   public class ElementBase extends UINamingContainer {
       ...
   }
   ```
2. and a composite components with the following interface

   ```
   <composite:interface componentType="elementBase">
       ... some attributes, value holder, ..
   </composite:interface>
   ```
3. provide a `faces-config.xml` within the deployed jar, to indicate that the jar contains annotated classes. The structure of the deployed jar should look like

   ```
   -- META-INF
       |-- resources
       |    |-- components
       |         |-- elementBase.xhtml
       |-- faces-config.xml
   -- com
       |-- example
       |    |-- ElementBase.class
   ```
4. deploy the jar within the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the web application.

## Research/Related links and topics

- [JEE6> Packaging JSF facelets (xhtml) and ManagedBeans as JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104498)
- [Java EE6 Tutorial: Application Configuration Resource File](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnawp.html)
- [JSF facelets template packaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290482)
- [How to create a modular JSF 2.0 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199458)