# Is it possible to share the same MVC between external Jars and a War in Servlet 3.0 environment?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlet-3.0

I understand that `Servlet 3.0`'s enhancements have made it possible to display a `.jsp` from a `.jar`, based on [Can I serve JSPs from inside a JAR in lib, or is there a workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013917/can-i-serve-jsps-from-inside-a-jar-in-lib-or-is-there-a-workaround)

However, I don't seem to be able to connect my View (jsp in jar WEB-INF/lib Tomcat 7 and classic spring MVC context configuration in a War) with the Model and the Controller of my Web App.

Is there a good way to share the dispatcher Servlet, or perhaps create a `CustomViewResolver` which could scan `.jsp`s included in external `JAR`s, and actually plug my `jar` into a unique spring context?

Comment: I think this answer could also apply to JSPs :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104498/jee6-packaging-jsf-facelets-xhtml-and-managedbeans-as-jar

Comment: what's the problem exactly with connecting Servlet3 jsps and controller?

Comment: the problem is the way to connect a classic controller defined in a classic web-app (WAR) to views (jsp) included only in external jar !

Answer (score 1):

With JSP you have the problem of compilation.
So you at least need to precompile them, to have them included. Then it should be possible, since after compilation a JSP is basically a Servlet.

If you would use another view technology like Velocity, Freemarker or JSF based on Facelets, you can very easily use a classpath based ViewResolver.