# put xhtml page into a jar maven project

Tags: maven, jsf-2, jar, war

I have 2 maven projects (war and jar).
I would like to put jsf pages into the jar project that will be used in my webapp page.

This is the structure of my jar

> > JarProject
> >      |-- META-INF
> >      |    |-- resources
> >      |    |    | -- myPages
> >      |    |    |    |    `-- pages.xhtml
> >      |    |-- faces-config.xml
> >      | com
> >      | |....

In my web project, I put my jar in

> WEB-INF\lib

and I included my page like this

```
<ui:include src="/myPages/pages.xhtml" />
```

I tried this solution, but it didn't work, can you tel me what I've missed

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104498/jee6-packaging-jsf-facelets-xhtml-and-managedbeans-as-jar and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531432/jsf2-pages-into-a-jar

Comment: Thxs for your reply, I've tried this, but it didn't works

Comment: @Sarroura show us your `faces-config.xml` file

Comment: Which application server do you use? Is it JavaEE 5 or 6?

Comment: @partlov I put an empty Faces-config.xml

Comment: @Charlee Chitsuk I'm using Tomcat

Comment: @Sarroura see `faces-config.xml` file from [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6105009/759126). It should not be completely empty.

Comment: AFAIK, you may need to use the `FaceletsResourceResolver` as mentioning at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587808/how-to-use-facelets-composition-with-files-from-another-context

Comment: @partlov, I used the same faces-config

Comment: Tomcat does not support this feature. Only JavaEE6 application server does.

Comment: OP is using Maven. This requires understanding how Maven structures the projects differently from the standard and how Maven needs to be configured to build the proper JAR. The answers which are linked in the previous comments do not assume Maven, they just assume standard Servlet spec. Important fact is that `/META-INF/resources` is supposed to end up in **classpath**, not in **webcontent**.

Comment: There is no differnce by using maven, but @CharleeChitsuk said that Tomcat does not support this