# Make attributes of Composite Component from JAR available in autocomplete

Tags: jsf, jar, rad, composite-component, code-completion

I've made a Composite Component and archived it in a *.jar file. My solution is based on this tutorial : [How to package JSF2 composite component as distributable JAR](http://www.kianworknotes.com/2013/01/how-to-package-jsf2-composite-component.html) and this question: [Java EE6> Packaging JSF facelets (xhtml) and ManagedBeans as JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104498/jee6-packaging-jsf-facelets-xhtml-and-managedbeans-as-jar). 
Everything works fine but I can't used autocomplete in Eclipse to add attributes of Composite Component when I add it through *.jar file. When I add it manually, i.e. place code in `resources/composite_components` everything works fine. 
I'm using RAD 8.5.5 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note: not a JSF problem, but an IDE problem. My Eclipse+JbossTools also fails here.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue ?

Comment: @Ced, unfortunately not :(