# Locating Javascript and other resources in modular JSF 2.2.x application

Tags: jsf-2, tomcat6, jsf-2.2

I have a modular JSF application. Facelets are stored in the module in META-INF/resources. I added a custom FaceletsResourceResolver (as demonstrated in this post [How to create a modular JSF 2.0 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199458/how-to-create-a-modular-jsf-2-0-application/6201044#6201044)) and all of this works well with .xhtml - Files. Now I am trying to add other resources in the same fashion and it's not working.

Let's say I have this structure in the module:

```
/META-INF/resources
/META-INF/resources/foo
/META-INF/resources/foo/bar.xhtml
/META-INF/resources/foo/bar.js
```

Now the application resolves /foo/bar.xhtml just fine. But attempts to fetch /foo/bar.js simply fail with 404. I tried using

```
<h:outputScript library="modulename" name="foo/bar.js" />
```

as well as direct reference

```
<script language="text/javascript" src="/context/foo/bar.js"/>
```

both to no avail. I feel I am missing something. Can someone help me?

PS: using Apache Tomcat 6 and Eclipse-Juno for development.

Comment: Are you really using JSF 2.2? This isn't compatible with Servlet 2.5 containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'll ignore the fact that the mentioned versions in your question in its current form is confusing. JSF 2.2 (as you tagged) requires a minimum of Servlet 3.0. Tomcat 6 (as you mentioned) is a Servlet 2.5 container (and a quite old one either). This is not going to work together. Also noted should be that the `FaceletsResourceResolver` which you found there is only necessary when you're using Servlet 2.5 or are using a very early JBoss AS 6 version.*

---

The library name does here not represent the JAR file name, but the subfolder where all of those resources commonly belong to. So when you have a

```
<h:outputScript library="modulename" name="foo/bar.js" />
```

then the following structure is expected in the JAR:

```
/META-INF/resources/modulename
/META-INF/resources/modulename/foo
/META-INF/resources/modulename/foo/bar.xhtml
/META-INF/resources/modulename/foo/bar.js
```

Alternatively, you can keep your original structure and use

```
<h:outputScript library="foo" name="bar.js" />
```

depending on the meaning of the actual value of `foo`.

#### See also:

- [Packaging Facelets files (templates, includes, composites) in a JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531432/packaging-facelets-pages-in-a-jar)

Comment: Once more, much obliged.