# How to use JSF templates stored in a shared jar?

Tags: jsf

I am trying to store a set of JSF templates and other resources in a .jar file, which several webapps will draw from.  I found this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531432/packaging-facelets-files-templates-includes-composites-in-a-jar--), which seems to provide instructions for the very thing I'm trying to do.  However, while I can load images from the shared jar, I cannot get JSF templates to work.  I get a file not found error.

I'm using Open Liberty 18.0.0.4, and the jar is stored in the `${server.config.dir}/lib/global` directory, which I understand makes the contents available to all webapps.

Here is the output of `jar tf` of the shared jar.

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/resources/common/images/ufo.png
META-INF/resources/common/jsf/template.xhtml
```

This is the `template.xhtml` from the shared jar.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Title from template</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        This is content from the template<br/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Turning to my webapp, here is the directory layout.

```
/WEB-INF
/WEB-INF/classes
/WEB-INF/web.xml
/META-INF
/imageTest.xhtml
/localTemplate.xhtml
/localJSFTest.xhtml
/sharedJarJSFTest.xhtml
```

The `imageTest.xhtml` simply displays the `ufo.png` from the shared jar, and this facelet works without a problem.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Test Image</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        I can see this image.<br/>
        <h:graphicImage library="common" name="images/ufo.png" alt="ufo"/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

The `localJSFTest.xhtml` uses the `localTemplate.xhtml`, which is part of the webapp.  This also works.

`localJSFText.html`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition template="localTemplate.xhtml" />
    </h:body>
</html>
```

`localTemplate.xhtml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Title from local template</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        This is content from the LOCAL template<br/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

The problem comes when `sharedJarJSFText.xhtml` tries to use `template.xhtml` (posted above) from the shared jar.

`sharedJarJSFText.xhtml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition template="/common/jsf/template.xhtml" />
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I get the following error when I try to access `sharedJarJSFText.xhtml` in the browser.

```
/common/jsf/template.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource

viewId=/sharedJarJSFTest.xhtml
location=/home/jmac/Programming/NetBeansProjects/TestJSFWebApp/src/main/webapp/sharedJarJSFTest.xhtml
phaseId=RENDER_RESPONSE(6)

Caused by:
java.io.FileNotFoundException - /common/jsf/template.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.resolveURL(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:300)
```

I think I'm following the instructions in the above linked SO answer, so I'm not sure why this isn't working.

In another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199458/how-to-create-a-modular-jsf-2-0-application/6201044#6201044), user BalusC explains that since the Servlet 3.0 spec writing a custom `ResourceResolver` is unnecessary.  This version of Open Liberty uses the Servlet 4.0 spec.

If helpful, here is the feature list from the `server.xml` for this Open Liberty server.

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
    <feature>jsf-2.3</feature>
</featureManager>
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question

Comment: No problem.  I appreciate the quick reply.  It is basically a duplicate question, but I can't get the duplicate question's answer to work.  I had suspected that I was using Open Liberty wrong, so maybe I'm asking, how do I do this with Open Liberty?  I thought maybe I was not activating a feature that I needed.  But I just tried this on Payara 5, and I'm running into the same problem.  I can get an image from the shared jar, but not the JSF template.  Still, I imagine I'm overlooking something very basic.

Comment: Try adding the jar in your war. It might just be it does not work from a 'global' folder. And do you have an (empty) faces-config,xml in the jar?