# Tomcat 7 / TomEE 1.6 @Webfilter annotation. Not being loaded from Jar

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlet-filters, apache-tomee

Is there something special I have to do to enable Jar scanning for `@WebFilter` in Tomcat7 or TomEE 1.6? I have an empty 3.0 spec `web.xml`, a `beans.xml` in web-inf, and my `@WebFilter` is in a CDI compliant JAR (not that the servlet spec would really care I guess).

The filter works if I enable it manually in the `web.xml`. If I copy/paste the class into the WAR project, Tomcat/Tomee picks up the `@WebFilter` annotated class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isn't the jar filtered? Maybe an ignored prefix

Comment: ah shoot... how do you tell?

Comment: does it start by one of these prefixes http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomee/tomee/trunk/container/openejb-core/src/main/resources/default.exclusions ?

Comment: FYI Never figured this out, but it wasn't being ignored. Accepted because I learned something new about filtered jars.

Answer (score 3):

I was scratching my head too over my `@WebFilter` class not being picked up, and ended up reading something (can't remember where) that referenced the `metadata-complete` attribute in the web.xml root tag needing to be false, or just not added to the tag at all (default is false).

When I removed that attribute from my web.xml root tag so that it looked like this:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
```

it picked up my `@WebFilter` class immediately, with no references in the web.xml file.  Not sure if this helps, but hopefully it will help someone.

Comment: This was very helpful. I was frustrated and even debugged the tomcat/servlet code base. So basically what happens is if the `metadata-complete` is set to true, we say the web.xml is complete and don't need to scan for annotation such as `WebFilter`. However it improves the startup time. See more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820379/what-to-do-with-annotations-after-setting-metadata-complete-true-which-resolv

Comment: That's  exactly it!!! Tks a lot!!!