# Websphere 8 server deploys JAX-WS module without error but service unavailable

Tags: web-services, deployment, websphere, jax-ws

I am Developing and Testing a @Stateless EJB wrapped into @Webservice, all works fine locally within RAD, but as soon as I deploy the EAR with its WAR module to a production server (8.0.5) the WSDL url returns 404 and no entries show up in the WAS console under Services.

My local WAS server in RAD is also 8.0.5.

8.0.5 is JEE6 compliant and should be scanning the annotation and generating the wsdl.

Comment: Check in the SystemOut.log, if application is successfully started.

Comment: Yes, the application start fine I get the green icon in the console and the other module in the EAR which is a simple Application WAR, is available.

Comment: Well I guess so much for scanning and tool auto-generation. But once I generated the physical webservices.xml and the wsdl myself and then referenced the wsdl location in the webservices.xml then all was OK. It popped up in the Service console.

Comment: Check, if you have web.xml in your WAR and if it is 3.0. Scanning is not enabled for modules earlier than 3.0, and application.xml earlier then 5.0.

Comment: Ff you have web.xml in your WAR and it is on 3.0 version, and if metadata-complete attribute is set to "true", then annotation scanning is not working. Try to change it to metadata-complete="false" and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thought of that but isn't it just a flag to skip scanning the jar libraries in /lib, and the project classes get scanned anyway? As indicated here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820379/what-to-do-with-annotations-after-setting-metadata-complete-true-which-resolv)