# Java EE servlet error - duplicate URL pattern

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, ejb, webclient, managed-bean

I'm in the process of making a prototype banking application for one of my assignments. I've successfully created the persistence API, EJBs, and all required tables. However, when I create the WebClient for my application and integrate that with the Enterprise application and try to run it, I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet [`RegistrationPortImpl`] and
>   Servlet [`RegistrationRequesterPortImpl`] have the same url pattern

The WebClient only has the default `index.xhtml` file on it and I have not yet integrated to managed beans with it.

I just wanted to check if my application would run after the integration with enterprise application before I make any advances.

Comment: Have you added any url patterns to these servlets?

Comment: I haven't created any serverlets, its simply using JSF. After more research came across a blog that actually fixed this issue by adding the following line in the web.xml file. 
metadata-complete="true"
However, I don't know why this solves the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the entry `metadata-complete=true` in the `web-app` tag like this:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0"
  metadata-complete="true">
```

This [post](http://thajudahlim.blogspot.com.uy/2011/11/same-url-pattern-error-on-glassfish-ose.html) suggests something similar.
This entry disabled the scan for Servlet 3.0 specific annotations and web-fragments in `/WEB-INF/lib`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820379/what-to-do-with-annotations-after-setting-metadata-complete-true-which-resolv), [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/servlet-30-web-fragmentxml) and [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/cweb_webfragments.html).

Maybe you could check the URL patterns in your `web.xml` and what libraries your app use.

Answer (score 0):

In the `@WebServlet` put a unique url path for example `@WebServlet("/port") @WebServlet("/requestport")`

Annotate each of your servlet like this and then i believe this issue will not occur.

Comment: I haven't created any servlets, its simply using JSF. After more research came across a blog that actually fixed this issue by adding the following line in the web.xml file. 
metadata-complete="true"
However, I don't know why this solves the issue.

Comment: Ok right. There might be two runtimes configured for the project and duplicate libraries are added.

Comment: This might have the correct understanding of it https://stackoverflow.com/a/9820775/578855

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you meant by two run times? I'm quite new to this type of programming. How would I check if have two runtimes configured?