# Using Facelets as provided scope dependency

Tags: maven, jsf, ejb, java-ee-6, facelets

Im using this solution [Packaging facelets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531432/packaging-facelets-files-templates-includes-composites-in-a-jar) to package all common resources in a jar, including ui:composition elements, it works perfectly when i add the created jar as dependency to my projects in runtime or compile scope, but when i try to use **provided** scope it fails with NO RESOURCE FOUND

I also tried use one jar as **deployment.commonresources.jar** but fails when one controller is called because @postCostruct uses some @EJB's

I need to use this "dependency" in multiple projects

Comment: When using `provided` you are telling maven you already have all the required dependencies included in your main application. How do you include your dependencies?

Comment: As a deployment, is this correct..?