# Package JSF Composite Component into JAR

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, xml-namespaces, composite-component, modularity

When attempting to bundle our composite components into a jar and include as a dependency in another project, I followed the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8616120/4912604).

This works for everything except the composite component implementation. 
The folder structure for our common project is shown below:

```
CommonWebProject
 |-- META-INF
 |    |-- resources
 |    |    `-- common
 |    |         |-- css
 |    |         |    ...
 |    |         |-- js
 |    |         |    ...
 |    |         |-- components
 |    |         |    `-- comment.xhtml
 |    |         |-- templates
 |    |         |    `-- defaultTemplate.xhtml
 |    |-- faces-config.xml
 |    `-- MANIFEST.MF
 :
```

comment.xhtml consists of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

<composite:interface>

</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
  <p>TESTING!</p>
</composite:implementation>

</html>
```

The actual implementation looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:csxc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/csxcomponent" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:common="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/common"
    template="/common/templates/defaultTemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="head">
    </ui:define>

    <common:comment/>

  </ui:composition>
```

Here the template "defaultTemplate.xhtml" that is being pulled from the common jar is working correctly, but not the  tag. Inspecting the page just shows the tag.

[image]

Any ideas why?

Comment: Does it work when you include all in your project directly? Anything special in your faces-config.xml? Anything special in your web.xml? Versions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
CommonWebProject
 |-- META-INF
 |    |-- resources
 |    |    `-- common
 |    |         |-- components
 |    |         |    `-- comment.xhtml
 :    :         :
```

Thus, the resource-relative path is `/common/components/comment.xhtml`.

However,

```
xmlns:common="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/common"
...
<common:comment />
```

the XML namespace basically says that `comment.xhtml` is inside `/common` folder. It's actually not there. It's actually inside `/common/components` folder.

Align out it.

```
xmlns:common="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/common/components"
...
<common:comment />
```

I have in the meanwhile fixed the answer you found there.

Comment: Ok great! I've got that working. If I wanted to include java classes would they fall under the 'components' folder as well?

Comment: @BalusC Congratulation on becoming 2nd top user on Stackoverflow. You really deserve it.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: Thanks :)