# JSF-1.1 I18n- How to register Custom ResourceBundle in faces-config.xml

Tags: jsf, internationalization, faces-config

I was working on Internationalizing the messages/strings in my older JSF-1.x project when I found that the UTF-8 rendering was not being applied on the messages.

I ran across a similar problem here:- [i18n with UTF-8 encoded properties files in JSF 2.0 appliaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645491/i18n-with-utf-8-encoded-properties-files-in-jsf-2-0-appliaction)

But that would work for JSF-2 aplication and I cant register my Custom Resource Bundle in the same way as explained there.(Deployment error of namespace not matching shows up.)

Need help to register my Custom Resource Bundle in faces-config.xml for JSF-1.x.

(We had used message-bundle in there. But I cannot register my bundle class in message-bundle like we can in resource-bundle tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `JSF-1.x` , there is no support to register my own Custom `ResourceBundle` class.

Therefore, need to go forward to create a custom tag `<x:loadBundle>` which encodes the Properties file in the correct encoding.

Refer [Facelets custom tag not rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118309/facelets-custom-tag-not-rendering) to register your `Tag Library XML` in your `web.xml`. Then in your `TagLibrary XML`, have this config:-

```
<tag>
            <tag-name>loadBundle</tag-name>
            <handler-class>org.somepackage.facelets.tag.jsf.handler.LoadBundleHandler</handler-class>
</tag>
```

And extend your custom LoadBundleHandler to extend the TagHandler facelets class-
(The code would be the same as the LoadBundleHandler @ `com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.core.LoadBundleHandler`

And now you could override the Control class as in my referred post in the question.
So overall your class would look like this:-

```
public final class LoadBundleHandler extends TagHandler {


    private static final String BUNDLE_EXTENSION = "properties";    // The default extension for langauge Strings (.properties)

    private static final String CHARSET = "UTF-8";

    private static final Control UTF8_CONTROL = new UTF8Control();  

    private final static class ResourceBundleMap implements Map {
        private final static class ResourceEntry implements Map.Entry {

            protected final String key;

            protected final String value;

            public ResourceEntry(String key, String value) {
                this.key = key;
                this.value = value;
            }

            public Object getKey() {
                return this.key;
            }

            public Object getValue() {
                return this.value;
            }

            public Object setValue(Object value) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }

            public int hashCode() {
                return this.key.hashCode();
            }

            public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                return (obj instanceof ResourceEntry && this.hashCode() == obj
                        .hashCode());
            }
        }

        protected final ResourceBundle bundle;

        public ResourceBundleMap(ResourceBundle bundle) {
            this.bundle = bundle;
        }

        public void clear() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
            try {
                bundle.getString(key.toString());
                return true;
            } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        public Set entrySet() {
            Enumeration e = this.bundle.getKeys();
            Set s = new HashSet();
            String k;
            while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                k = (String) e.nextElement();
                s.add(new ResourceEntry(k, this.bundle.getString(k)));
            }
            return s;
        }

        public Object get(Object key) {
            try {
                return this.bundle.getObject((String) key);
            } catch( java.util.MissingResourceException mre ) {
                return "???"+key+"???";
            }
        }

        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return false;
        }

        public Set keySet() {
            Enumeration e = this.bundle.getKeys();
            Set s = new HashSet();
            while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                s.add(e.nextElement());
            }
            return s;
        }

        public Object put(Object key, Object value) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        public void putAll(Map t) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        public Object remove(Object key) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        public int size() {
            return this.keySet().size();
        }

        public Collection values() {
            Enumeration e = this.bundle.getKeys();
            Set s = new HashSet();
            while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                s.add(this.bundle.getObject((String) e.nextElement()));
            }
            return s;
        }
    }

    private final TagAttribute basename;

    private final TagAttribute var;


    public LoadBundleHandler(TagConfig config) {
        super(config);
        this.basename = this.getRequiredAttribute("basename");
        this.var = this.getRequiredAttribute("var");
    }


    public void apply(FaceletContext ctx, UIComponent parent)
            throws IOException, FacesException, FaceletException, ELException {
        UIViewRoot root = ComponentSupport.getViewRoot(ctx, parent);
        ResourceBundle bundle = null;
        FacesContext faces = ctx.getFacesContext();
        String name = this.basename.getValue(ctx);
        try {
            ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            if (root != null && root.getLocale() != null) {
                bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(name, root.getLocale(), cl, UTF8_CONTROL);
            } else {
                bundle = ResourceBundle
                        .getBundle(name, Locale.getDefault(), cl);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new TagAttributeException(this.tag, null , e);
        }
        ResourceBundleMap map = new ResourceBundleMap(bundle);
        faces.getExternalContext().getRequestMap().put(this.var.getValue(ctx),
                map);
    }



    protected static class UTF8Control extends Control {
        public ResourceBundle newBundle
            (String baseName, Locale locale, String format, ClassLoader loader, boolean reload)
                throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, IOException
        {
            String bundleName = toBundleName(baseName, locale);
            String resourceName = toResourceName(bundleName, BUNDLE_EXTENSION);
            ResourceBundle bundle = null;
            InputStream stream = null;
            if (reload) {
                URL url = loader.getResource(resourceName);
                if (url != null) {
                    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                    if (connection != null) {
                        connection.setUseCaches(false);
                        stream = connection.getInputStream();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                stream = loader.getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
            }
            if (stream != null) {
                try {
                    bundle = new PropertyResourceBundle(new InputStreamReader(stream, UTF8_CONTROL));
                } finally {
                    stream.close();
                }
            }
            return bundle;
        }
    }


}
```

You could even skip the `basename` config in `<x:loadbundle var="msg basename="resources">` by removing the `basename` property in this class.